# Multiply defined symbols: mysqlclient, pthread-win32

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, visual-studio, pthreads

Continuing my porting project ... trying to get a Linux C++ app working on windows with Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

This is a multi-threaded app, so I've brought [pthread-win32](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) into the mix.  It also uses MySQL, so I've installed the binary 32 bit [MySQL C Connector library](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) as well.

Everything is going fine up until VS tries to link it.  Then I get this:

```
pthreadVSE2.lib(pthreadVSE2.dll) : error LNK2005: _pthread_exit already defined in mysqlclient.lib(my_winthread.obj)
pthreadVSE2.lib(pthreadVSE2.dll) : error LNK2005: _pthread_join already defined in mysqlclient.lib(my_winthread.obj)
pthreadVSE2.lib(pthreadVSE2.dll) : error LNK2005: _pthread_create already defined in mysqlclient.lib(my_winthread.obj)
```

Turns out that the MySQL devs ran into the same problem (lack of pthreads on windows), so they rolled part of the pthread library into their library (or rolled their own with the same function names/signatures - I haven't looked that close).

But it's only part of it - I tried removing pthread-win32 from the link thinking that maybe the mysqlclient library had all of pthreads embedded in it - but that produces lots of unresolved symbols.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?  Complete windows developer newbie here, so no suggestion is to dumb!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if anybody comes across the same problem, here's how I solved it.  I went into the MySQL connector source code and renamed the multiply defined functions and recompiled the library.

```
pthread_exit() renamed to mysql_pthread_exit()
pthread_join() renamed to mysql_pthread_join()
pthread_create() renamed to mysql_pthread_create()
```

Declarations are in include/my_pthread.h, implementations in mysys/my_winthread.c  They aren't called anywhere within the library.

This allows for a clean compile & link.  The MySQL stuff isn't in the multi-threaded part of this piece of my code, and it appears to be working fine.

It's not an ideal solution, because I now have to cart around a modified version of the MySQL connector library, and re-do the mod whenever a new version comes out.  But it works for now.